# How can I reverse just the key to a dictionary in python but not the value

Tags: python, dictionary

i need help for a dictionary in python I explain :
actually i have a dictionary like this :
`{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}`
but i would like this :
`{"c":1, "b":2, "a":3}`

for this I have made this :

```
new_dict={}
for k,v in dictionnary1.items():
  dict_element = {k:v}
  dict_element.update(new_dict)
  new_dict = dict_element
print(new_dict)
```

but the OUTPUT is that :
`{"c":3, "b":2, "a":1}`

how can I resolve this ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the keys in reverse sort order regardless of the order of the keys currently in the `dict`?

Comment: I would like with my actual dictionnary {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3} have something like this {"c":1, "b":2, "a":3} i have make a mistake on the title

Comment: I'm asking what are the order of the keys *now* in the `dict`? Are you sure they are in that order now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
In [1]: x = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}

In [2]: new_x = {key: value for key, value in zip(reversed(x.keys()), x.values())}

In [3]: new_x
Out[3]: {'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'a': 3}
```

Basically you just reverse the order of the keys and build a new dict from the reverse keys and values